# Using a Batch Script to Move Specific Files with Specific File Contents

Tags: command-line, batch

I am looking to find a file with the contents 'Radiac' in one particular folder and then move all those files to a another folder.

For example: I have might have 3 identical file-names with different extensions like below. Let's say, the content Radiac is only in the `jones.pdf` file. What I want is a batch script that finds this specific content and then moves all the 3 file-names? I hope that makes sense. I'm new to windows batch scripting.

```
jones.pdf
jones.xml
jones.txt
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you would be better off with powerscript, python, or perl for this. You will also need to find a library or tool that can spit raw text out of a pdf. PDF is a specific format, not just text. This will be almost impossible to do with just batch. Seems like a stack overflow question to me.

Comment: Hi Eddie, Thanks for the response. In this case, the .pdf document is searchable. However, to simplify things lets say it is the jones.txt file instead of the jones.pdf file. What I am looking to do is find the filename with this specific content then xcopy this filename.*.* and its associated extensions to another folder.

Comment: @B.Ng `filename.*.*` do you really mean this (It doesn't match your example filenames)? Or do you mean `filename.*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use just batch and you are ok with the pdf support not being there.

Try This:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /m /c:"Radiac" *') do xcopy "%%~na.*" "C:\path\to\your\folder"
```

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to use this command. Do you mind explaining how it works?

Comment: It would probably be easiest to place the two lines in a .bat file and then run it from the directory that has the files you want to search. You will also need to change "c:\path\to\your\folder" to the path that you want the files to be copied into/

Comment: I have the 2 lines in the batch files. I've placed the batch file in the directory with the files I want to run. However, whenever I run it, I get "FINDSTR: Cannot open IN." IN is the directory with the files.

Comment: Hi Eddie, I appreciate the help. I changed the extension to include all files and it worked. For some reason StackExchange does not show asterisks. Now I just how to figure out copying files with the .pdf extension.

Comment: Ahh sorry about that! Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @B.Ng Try using the following for the xcopy bit `xcopy "%%~na.*" "C:\path\to\your\folder"`. That should copy all files matching the found name with any extension.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thanks - I updated the answer to include the suggestion.

Comment: @B.Ng THis might be a start for the pdf piece. But it is really out of the scope of this community. It has a batch mode that I think you would be able to make use of http://www.colorpilot.com/extract-pdf-text.html

Comment: Hi David, thanks. Adding the "%%~na.*" didn't work as intended. It only copied one of the pdfs and ignored the rest. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @B.Ng It will copy all sets of all files starting with `name` where one of the files called `name` contains the text you are looking for. You shouldcheck that `findstr /m /c:"Radiac" *.*` outputs the filenames you expect (that actually contain the name `Radiac`.

Comment: Thanks David. Turns out that some of extensions had .txt.pdf. For example: jones.txt.pdf. I simply changed the findstr /m /c:"Radiac" *.* to findstr /m /c:"Radiac" * and it seems to be working now. I appreciate everyone's help and time.